# mathematic library for ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
I'm working with ros on a project for velocity estimation of a quadrotor based on optical flow. After having acquired images from the camera mounted on the uav and having computed optical flow I need to set a system of linear equations and then compute the pseudo-inverse. Is there a library "easy to use" in ros for such things?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47648/mathematic-library-for-ros/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically, you can use anything.
The best practice would be to use a ROS-independent system library instead of a custom ROS package for such things.

[Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) is quite commonly used and should do what you want.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3